# can i run multiple instance of logstash in the same server?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to get **RSS feed** from five news website with **RSS logstash** input plugin and as well tweet of twitter with twitter plugin I create one **logstash** config file for RSS and one for twitter. my question is, can I run multiple instance of logstash by this command `bin/logstash -f first_config.conf` and `bin/logstash -f second_config.conf` if I do, will I face with bottleneck problem ?

Comment: You can run multiple instances of `logstash` if you're having conf files for each of them.

Comment: does all of the input plugin of logstash can write data to multiple index of  one node of 'elasticsearch'  ?

Comment: You mean writing data to different indices which are being created on a single node?

Comment: yes i want to  write data from twitter to index by the name twitter_news and rss data to index by the name of rss_index_english

Comment: yes you can do that.

Comment: Or you can use Logstash with multiple inputs, using [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) to deal with the different types

Answer (score 1):

[You want to run "Multiple Pipelines".](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/multiple-pipelines.html#multiple-pipelines)
If you need to run more than one pipeline in the same process, Logstash provides a way to do this through a configuration file called pipelines.yml. See docs in the link.